# All cards are added to the same hand despite creating two different instances in Java

Tags: java, multiple-instances

I'm creating a blackjack game in Java. I need to have multiple players and need a hand class to store the cards that have been pulled from the deck. I have a hand class that functions, but even when I create two separate hand instances, dealing a card to either hand adds them to both hands.

This is my hand class code:

```java
public class Hand2 {
    
    private List<Cards> hand;
    private Cards cards;
    private int handValue;
    
    public Hand2(List<Cards> hand) {
        
        this.hand = hand;   
    }
    
    private Cards addCard(Deck deck) {
        hand.add(deck.dealCard());
        return cards;
    }
    
    public int getHandValue() {
        for (Cards cards : hand ) {
            handValue += cards.getValue();
        }
        return handValue;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Hand: " + hand;
    }
```

And below I am testing it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //Testing
     List<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();
     
     Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
                    
        Hand2 hand = new Hand2(cards);
        Hand2 hand2 = new Hand2(cards);
        
        hand.addCard(deck);
        hand2.addCard(deck);
        hand2.addCard(deck);
        System.out.println(hand2);
            System.out.println(hand.getHandValue());
        System.out.println(hand2.getHandValue());
   
 }
```

Terminal:

```
Hand: [Three of Diamonds, Four of Clubs, Jack of Hearts]
17
17
```

But I get the same hand value for either hand.

Comment: Because you pass the same `List<Cards>` to both `Hand`(s).

Comment: You are passing the same List to both your generated Objects so both will use that one List. If you want each Hand to have it's own different List of cards you need to pass different objects, because there will not be any automatic cloning when passing around Objects in java.

Comment: why not just: `public Hand2() { this.hand = new ArrayList<Cards>(); }` or initialize it directly at the class variable level

Comment: Thankyou guys! This helped a lot. I used your solution Tan Yu Hau Sean and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Why is there a class called `Cards`? It should probably be `Card`

Answer (score 0):

As some have already noted, the same list of cards is shared between all hands. Another problem I see in you code is that you're using fields (`cards`, `handValue`) when you should use local variables.

Try this:

```
public class Hand2 {
    private final List<Cards> hand = new ArrayList<>();

    public Hand2() {
    }
    
    private Cards addCard(Deck deck) {
        Cards cards = deck.dealCard();
        hand.add(cards);
        return cards;
    }
    
    public int getHandValue() {
        int handValue = 0;
        for (Cards cards : hand ) {
            handValue += cards.getValue();
        }
        return handValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hand: " + hand;
    }
```